# How to pull a rebased branch without deleting it

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request

During code review, I have a developer who likes to pull down the branch they are reviewing and then run the code themselves. If there is an issue, the pull request is rejected and the feature branch owner will make updates to the branch accordingly.

The updates are made via rebasing. This obviously means that when the original developer is re-reviewing the pull request, they encounter conflicts that come along with pulling a rebased remote feature branch.

The developer performing the code review is annoyed that they have to delete the local feature branch and pull the remote feature branch. Annoyances asside, is there a `git` command to handle/ignore the conflicts when pulling a rebased remote?

Note: this is not a shared branch, test branch, master branch, etc. These are purely feature branches that are in development.

Comment: You can try to - commit your local changes, git fetch remote, and then checkout to the required feature branch to be reviewed?

Comment: The reviewer doesn't do any change on the branch right?

Comment: @GaëlJ Correct. The reviewer is not making any changes.

Comment: @AmitDash The reviewer is not making local changes, they are simply reviewing the code and then pulling down rebased updates as needed.

Comment: Wont a reset work? git reset origin/branch_under_review

Comment: Then the simple command `git pull` should work. Why are there conflicts when no changes or commits are made by the reviewer?

Comment: @AmitDash Lets say original state of branch has commit head `dcf81dff my-commit-message`. Code review is made and the pull request is declined. A developer now makes updates to that feature branch and then rebase squashes those updates. The commit head now would change to `2654c804 my-commit-message`. If the original tester goes to pull updates, clearly there is a conflict here - the commit head/history has changed on them.

Comment: Change of commit head just from the developer side shouldn't result in conflicts. Rather conflicts would have been caused if there are commits on the reviewers / testers machine as well and that too on overlapping files.

Comment: I don't know why @GaëlJ's answer got downvoted. His middle answer is the simplest and most effective: `git fetch` (instead of `git pull`) and then from the feature branch do a `git reset --hard origin/feature-branch`.

Answer (score 1):

The reviewer could *not* checkout to a local branch but just do `git checkout origin/branch-to-review` when (s)he needs to review.

---

The reviewer can also use `reset` but I don't see how faster it is compared to removing a branch:

```
git checkout branch-to-review
git fetch
git reset origin/branch-to-review --hard
```

---

Also note that just `git pull --rebase` should work with a warning but still works. *(Assuming reviewer doesn't do any change on the branch)*

Comment: "git pull should work" - Are you sure? Lets say original state of branch has commit head `dcf81dff my-commit-message`. Code review is made and the pull request is declined. A developer now makes updates to that feature branch and then rebase squashes those updates. The commit head now would change to `2654c804 my-commit-message`. If the original tester goes to pull updates, clearly there is a conflict here - the commit head/history has changed on them.

Comment: Continuing my message above: this is why you have to do a `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` when pushing a rebased branch from local to remote - because the history of the branch has now been altered and git thinks "things have changed".

Comment: If the devs are doing force pushes (which are ideally not recommended), the only option is then for reviewer to delete their local branch before pulling.

Comment: "which are ideally not recommended" Are you unfamiliar with rebase and squashing? How do you do that without a --force-with-lease on your own local branch?

Comment: @GaëlJ: I suggest you edit your answer to say "Also not that just `git pull --rebase` should work", so that will be true for everyone.

Comment: Updated to clarify the need to use rebase strategy when pulling